# One line is breaking my Entire code and im not sure why, an old function seems to be getting called for no reason

Tags: java, function, java.util.scanner

So we get to my issue if we follow the progression of these functions in my code.

```
questionTime()
menuValid()
keepCounting()
```

then within the keepCounting() function the line `int q1_input = q1guess.nextInt();` seems to loop all the back to questionTime(), as "please pick a valid option is printed" i'm assuming its a scanner issue but cant work it out.

Heres my code for reference:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class Menu {

    public static void questionTime() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {int menu_input = scan.nextInt();
            if(menu_input>4 && menu_input < 9){
                scan.close();
                System.out.println("Please pick a valid option.");
                questionTime();
            }
            if(menu_input>9 || menu_input<1){
                scan.close();
                System.out.println("Please pick a valid option.");
                questionTime();
            }
            else{
                scan.close();
                menuValid(menu_input);
            }

        } catch(Exception e) {
            scan.close();
            System.out.println("ths one");
            questionTime();

            }
    }

    public static void menuValid(int menu_input) {
        System.out.println(menu_input);
        if(menu_input == 1){
            keepCounting();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("P4CS Mini Applications");
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println("Please Select an option:");
        System.out.println("1) Keep Counting Game");
        System.out.println("2) Number Conversion Tool");
        System.out.println("3) Universal Product Code (UPC) Calculator");
        System.out.println("4) Universal Product Code (UPC) Checker");
        System.out.println("9) Quit");
        System.out.println("Please enter option");

        questionTime();

        }

    public static void keepCounting(){
        System.out.println("Keep Counting");
        System.out.println("-------------");
        System.out.println("You will be presented with 8 addition questions. After the first question, the left-hand operand is the result of the previous addition");
        System.out.println("Press enter to start...");

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String ETS;
        boolean pass = false;
        while(pass == false){
            ETS = scan.nextLine();
            if(ETS.equals("")){
            pass = true;
            }
        scan.close();

        }

        Random rand = new Random();
        int max = 11;
        int maxPOM = 2;

        int LHN = 0;
        int RHN = 0;

        while(LHN == 0 || RHN == 0){
            LHN = rand.nextInt(max);
            RHN = rand.nextInt(max);
        }

        int POM = rand.nextInt(maxPOM);

        int ans1 = 0;
        
        if(POM == 0){
            System.out.println("Question 1: " + LHN + " + " + RHN + " =");
            ans1 = (LHN + RHN);
        }
        if(POM == 1){
            System.out.println("Question 1: " + LHN + " - " + RHN + " =");
            ans1 = (LHN - RHN);
        }

        System.out.println(ans1);

        Scanner q1guess = new Scanner(System.in);
        int q1_input = q1guess.nextInt();
        q1guess.close();
 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you close the `Scanner` you've attached to `System.in` you are also closing `System.in` itself: any subsequent attempts to read input data will quietly yield no data because the stream is closed.

Without doing much else to your program I've created a `Scanner` for `System.in` in your main method and passed it around to the others.  I've also removed explicit calls to `scan.close()` and have implemented try-with-resources as `Scanner` implements `AutoCloseable`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class so64211396 {
    public static void questionTime(Scanner scan) {
        try {
            int menu_input = scan.nextInt();
            if (menu_input > 4 && menu_input < 9) {
                // scan.close();
                System.out.println("Please pick a valid option.");
                questionTime(scan);
            }
            if (menu_input > 9 || menu_input < 1) {
                // scan.close();
                System.out.println("Please pick a valid option.");
                questionTime(scan);
            } else {
                // scan.close();
                menuValid(scan, menu_input);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // scan.close();
            System.out.println("ths one");
            questionTime(scan);

        }
    }

    public static void menuValid(Scanner scan, int menu_input) {
        System.out.println(menu_input);
        if (menu_input == 1) {
            keepCounting(scan);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.println("P4CS Mini Applications");
            System.out.println("----------------------");
            System.out.println("Please Select an option:");
            System.out.println("1) Keep Counting Game");
            System.out.println("2) Number Conversion Tool");
            System.out.println("3) Universal Product Code (UPC) Calculator");
            System.out.println("4) Universal Product Code (UPC) Checker");
            System.out.println("9) Quit");
            System.out.println("Please enter option");

            questionTime(scan);
        }
    }

    public static void keepCounting(Scanner scan) {
        System.out.println("Keep Counting");
        System.out.println("-------------");
        System.out.println(
                "You will be presented with 8 addition questions. After the first question, the left-hand operand is the result of the previous addition");
        System.out.println("Press enter to start...");

        String ETS;
        boolean pass = false;
        while (pass == false) {
            ETS = scan.nextLine();
            if (ETS.equals("")) {
                pass = true;
            }
            // scan.close();

        }

        Random rand = new Random();
        int max = 11;
        int maxPOM = 2;

        int LHN = 0;
        int RHN = 0;

        while (LHN == 0 || RHN == 0) {
            LHN = rand.nextInt(max);
            RHN = rand.nextInt(max);
        }

        int POM = rand.nextInt(maxPOM);

        int ans1 = 0;

        if (POM == 0) {
            System.out.println("Question 1: " + LHN + " + " + RHN + " =");
            ans1 = (LHN + RHN);
        }
        if (POM == 1) {
            System.out.println("Question 1: " + LHN + " - " + RHN + " =");
            ans1 = (LHN - RHN);
        }

        System.out.println(ans1);

        int q1_input = scan.nextInt();
        scan.close();

    }

}
```